# build cpp-netlib shared library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, dynamic-linking, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to use boost and cpp-netlib. The static library of cpp-netlib is about **40m**(release version), even linking to a small helloworld could be very **slow**. So I'd like to try dynamic **dll+ import lib** when developing, how can I build dll+lib for cpp-netlib?

I tried modify the CMakeLists.txt, add **SHARED** to the lines

```
add_library(cppnetlib-uri SHARED ${CPP-NETLIB_URI_SRCS})
add_library(cppnetlib-server-parsers SHARED ${CPP-NETLIB_HTTP_SERVER_SRCS})
add_library(cppnetlib-client-connections SHARED ${CPP-NETLIB_HTTP_CLIENT_SRCS})
```

but only **.dll** are generated, there's no **.lib**. Google says there must be export functions. So one way could be writing some dummy function and export them to generate the .lib?
Any other way?

Comment: Maybe the import libraries are generated somewhere else? Have you tried searching for `.lib` files in all the folders?

Comment: Yes I've searched for **.lib**, only exists **.dll**

Comment: From what You've shared, You're not generating any static libraries at all. Where is Your `add_library(static-lib STATIC ${SRCS})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible up to the current version 0.12.0 of cpp-netlib. The linker will only generate an import library for a DLL if (and only if) one or more functions are exported either using the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute or a DEF file. However, this is a feature currently not implemented in the code of the library. That is why after the build you can just see the DLLs, but not their respective import libraries.

This section of the [official documentation](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.12.0/getting_started.html#building-on-windows) confirms that only static libraries are meant to be generated:

> As of version 0.9.3, cpp-netlib produces three static libraries. Using
>   Visual C++ on Windows they are:
>
> cppnetlib-client-connections.lib
>   cppnetlib-server-parsers.lib
>   cppnetlib-uri.lib
>
> Users can find them in ~/cpp-netlib-build/libs/network/src.

If you want to substantially reduce the build time, I suggest you to [precompile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx) the library's headers that you include in your code.